# How can I clear the bestTranscritption object in speechRecognizer?

Tags: swift, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I've taken the demo below (which works from an online tutorial and trying to flesh it out for my own app.

I have been trying to get into the **speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask** object to reset it, as it contains the entire voice transcription from the very first word. I realize it uses the past few words to help it understand.

But at some point I would like to be able to clear it and continue with the transcribing.

Does anyone have any experience that could help me?

Thank you

```
 func startSpeechRecognition(){
        let node = audioEngine.inputNode
        let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
        
        node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat, block: { (buffer, _) in self.request.append(buffer)})
        
        audioEngine.prepare()
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch let error {
            alertView(message: "audioEngine start error")
        }
        
        guard let myRecognition = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
            self.alertView(message: "Recognition is not on your phone")
            return
        }
        
        if !myRecognition.isAvailable {
            self.alertView(message: "recognition is not available right now")
        }
        
        task = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { (response, error) in
            guard let response = response else {
                if error != nil {
                    self.alertView(message: error!.localizedDescription.debugDescription)
                } else {
                    self.alertView(message: "Unknow error in creating task")
                }
                return
            }
            
            let message = response.bestTranscription.formattedString
            self.label.text = message
        })
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: I wish there was a solution to this. Why can't we simply clear the transcription buffer?